# Unable to get a count with Xrmsrvc toolkit

Tags: javascript, crm

```
        $$.Toolkit.retrieveMultiple({
            entityName: "plus_interest",
            odataQuery: "$select=*&$filter=new_ConstituentId/Id eq guid'" + contactId + "'",
            async: false,
            successCallback: function (results) {
                if (results && results.length) {
                    $(results).each(function () {
                        var interest = this.plus_name.Name;
                        var itemText = '{0}'.Format(interest);

                        $('#interest-tree').append('<li>' + itemText + '</li>');
                    });
                    $('#interest-count').text(results.length);
                }
            },
            errorCallback: function (error) {
                throw error;
            }
        });
```

///The code should count all the interests associated with with the contact entity. However I can't seem to get a correct count with it.///
///For example, this retrieveMultiple request works just fine///

```
$$.Toolkit.retrieveMultiple({
            entityName: "new_gift",
            odataQuery: "$select=*&$filter=new_ConstituentDonor/Id eq guid'" + contactId + "'",
            async: false,
            successCallback: function (results) {
                if (results && results.length) {
                    $(results).each(function () {
                        var amount = Number(this.new_GiftAmount ? this.new_GiftAmount.Value : 0.00).toFixed(2);
                        var account = this.new_FundAccount && this.new_FundAccount != 'null' && this.new_FundAccount.Name != 'null' ? this.new_FundAccount.Name : 'Unknown';
                        var itemText = '<strong>${0}</strong> Gift to {1}'.Format(amount, account);

                        $('#gift-tree').append('<li>' + itemText + '</li>');
                    });

                    $('#gift-count').text(results.length);
                }
            },
            errorCallback: function (error) {
                throw error;
            }
        });
```